# DNA results for half sibling

Tags: dna

I had my DNA test done about 8 years ago with ancestry, I was contacted by a person who believed he could be my half brother from my father during World War 2,  all the information he had said my father was the father so this person who lives in another country took a DNA test with ancestry to see if we would be a match.  We have not so far, Would this mean he is not my half brother or should we do a private DNA test?

Answer (score 5):

Just so that I'm clear:

1. You have done a DNA test with Ancestry, have received your results, and have allowed Ancestry to match you with relatives.
2. This man has done a DNA test with Ancestry, has received his results, and has allowed Ancestry to match him with relatives.

If he does not show up in your DNA matches *and* all of the above is true, then he is not your half-brother.

If you want to double check, you can download your results from Ancestry and upload them to [GEDmatch.com](https://www.gedmatch.com/login1.php) (and have him do the same). Once both of your results are there, you can do a "one-to-one" match between your GEDmatch kit numbers. GEDmatch is free, so no extra monetary cost to either of you, but it can be a bit confusing to use. Once you've created an account, there are links to some guides to help you use it.

A private DNA test will not reveal anything that the Ancestry DNA test didn't.